# Does visual studio 2012 support Windows 7 SDK?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Does any body know whether Visual Studio 2012 support windows 7 sdk?
or how to configure vs2012 support windows 7 sdk?

Comment: I think the usual recommendation is to always use the most up to date version of the SDK, even if your *target* is an older version (unless the older version is no longer supported by that SDK)

Comment: It is already built-in, you'll need at least Update 1 to get the 7.1 SDK installed on your machine.